# Plotting Error bar on BarChart

Tags: plotting, charts

May I ask how to add error bar into the bar chart? 
The standard deviation and the mean are included in the below code.

```
JoinMean = Join[{MeanC5cm, SMeanC5cm}]
 {44.0215, 58.2535}
JoinStDv = Join[{Sd5, SSd5}]
 {3.31495, 3.72921}
 label = {"unstretch", "Stretch"};

BarChart[{JoinMean}, PlotLabel -> "5cm", 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "KΩ"}, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[label, Axis]]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the standard deviations to main data as metadata and use a custom `ChartElementFunction` that combines built-in `ChartElementFunction`s  with error lines using the information  passed as metadata:

```
ClearAll[errorLines]
errorLines[cedf__: "Rectangle"][t_: .5, style_: Thick] := 
  Module[{a = Mean[#[[1]]], b = -Subtract @@ #[[1]], c = #[[2, 2]], d = #3[[1]], 
     color = Darker @ Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]}, 
   {ChartElementData[cedf][##], color, style, Line[{{a, c - d}, {a, c + d}}],
     Line[Table[{a + i t b/2, c + j  d}, {j, {-1, 1}}, {i, {-1, 1}}]]}] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
JoinMean = {44.0215, 58.2535};
JoinStDv = {3.31495, 3.72921};

BarChart[Thread[JoinMean -> JoinStDv], PlotLabel -> "5cm", 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "KΩ"}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[label, Axis], ImageSize -> 400, 
 ChartElementFunction -> errorLines[][]]
```

[image]

Change the option setting for  `ChartElementFunction` to

```
errorLines["GradientScaleRectangle", "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow"][.8, Thickness[.02]]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: May i ask what is the first line of code trying to do?

Comment: @junliang04  it removes any store values and options associated with the symbol  `errorlines`.  It is good practice to do so before making a delayed assignment, like the line that follows. Have you had a chance to look up `ClearAll` in the documentation?

Comment: Thank you so much.